# Middleman image assets in Slim files not working when using webpack to build website

Tags: ruby, image, webpack, middleman

What is the correct format for my image links so they are compiled via webpack with the correct asset hash stamp? Right now, this is working correctly in my sass files, but not slim-lang html templates.

**Example HTML:**

```
p
  = image_tag 'favicons/testme.png'
  = tag :img, src: '/images/favicons/testme.png'
```

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

**My Webpack configuration:**

```
"use strict";

const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const ManifestPlugin = require("webpack-manifest-plugin");
const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, "build/assets");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    site: [
      path.join(__dirname, "/source/assets/stylesheets/site.scss"),
      path.join(__dirname, "/source/assets/javascripts/site.js")
    ]
  },

  output: {
    path: outputPath,
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  },

  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'node_modules'
    ]
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|ico|jpg|jpeg|png)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 5000,
              name: "[name]-[hash].[ext]",
              publicPath: '/assets/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['es2015']
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name]-[hash].css',
              publicPath: '/assets/'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'extract-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss'),
              ],
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'rev-manifest.json'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([outputPath], {
      root: __dirname
    })
  ]
};
```

**My Package Json File...**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --watch -d --progress --color",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --bail -p"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands": "^5.0.6",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular": "^5.0.6",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "normalize-scss": "^7.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.18",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "extract-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "precss": "^3.1.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: A quick reminder that question titles comprised of a list of tags are not particularly readable, [the reference discussion is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253028). If you wish to refer to some technologies in a normal usual sentence that's fine, but otherwise, just use the tag system.

Comment: I partially disagree @halfer and I rolled parts of your changes back. You changed the semantic english meaning of what I asked and therefor impacted my question negatively.  I agree about remove the terms, but search titles are used too. I updated it to meet you half way.

Comment: I appreciate the dialogue, Chris. After a question is edited, a question author is very welcome to carry on editing - it is a key part of the collaborative approach on the site. Your new title does not seem to be particularly taggy to me - I just fixed up the case subsequently. Much more readable than rev 1! (Case helps a lot with readability, I find, and it's worth noting all questions are edited to help their future audience).

Comment: I agree and love collaboration @halfer - I appreciate the insight too, and will adjust that going forward regarding the titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking for a solution for this issue, here is how I solved it.

First, I made sure that `activate :asset_hash` was turned on and `set :images_dir, 'assets/images/middleman'` was configured for my template assets.  Next, I broke up the assets used by webpack and middleman as shown below.  This allowed me to use code like this `link rel='shortcut icon' href=(image_path('favicons/favicon.ico'))` in my slim templates and have routable assets with hashes to break browser caching.

This looks something like this...
[image]